# How to Write Math Equation in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode

I am new in LaTex and need your help to write the following math equation in LaTeX.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! What have you done so far? Try `H_{k_p}=\frac{Y_{k_p}}{X_{k_p}}`

Comment: Comment not at all an answer. ff you can conveniently write what you mean without using double subscripts many readers will find it easier to understand you.

Answer (score 4):

One of the simplest ways to input an equation into LaTeX is to write something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
H_{k_p}=\frac{Y_{k_p}}{X_{k_p}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice how I've used the syntax of LaTeX to format the equation into the way you want - subscripts need the _ key, and I've used { } to indicate "k_p" should itself be a subscript.  Also note how to make fractions by using the \frac{}{} command.

Comment: You can mark inline code as such by using back ticks: `\``.

Answer (score 3):

A very simple one. You can use one of the three methods below (among others…)

### Edit

Use `\frac` instead of `\dfrac`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    In displaystyle
    \[H_{k_{p}}=\frac{Y_{k_{p}}}{X_{k_{p}}}\]

    Or inline $H_{k_{p}}=\dfrac{Y_{k_{p}}}{X_{k_{p}}}=\frac{Y_{k_{p}}}{X_{k_{p}}}=\tfrac{Y_{k_{p}}}{X_{k_{p}}}$.

    With a numbered and refenced equation (see \ref{eq:1})
    \begin{equation}
        H_{k_{p}}=\frac{Y_{k_{p}}}{X_{k_{p}}}\label{eq:1}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you use `\dfrac`? With normal `\baselineskip` this is likely to be too large in inline maths (and in your displayed equation it is the same as `\frac`).

Comment: Only because I made a copy/paste… :( Answer edited.

Comment: @Skillmon However, in inline mode with `\frac` or `\tfrac`, I dislike the numerator touching the line…

Comment: Use the following MWE and you'll instantly see why using `\dfrac` is a bad idea without additional line spread (in fact even a `\frac` is too large here): `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{amsmath,duckuments}\begin{document}\blindduck$H_{k_{p}}=\dfrac{Y_{k_{p}}}{X_{k_{p}}}$\blindduck\par \blindduck$H_{k_{p}}=\frac{Y_{k_{p}}}{X_{k_{p}}}$\blindduck\end{document}`.

Comment: Also the numerator doesn't touch the line, that's the fault of your pdf viewer.

Comment: your inline example now has one `\dfrac` and two `\frac`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not exactly! I let the `\dfrac`, and added one `\frac` and one `\tfrac`.

Comment: @Skillmon I agree with you: I usually use only `\frac`, but when I find it too cramped for space, I use `\dfrac`, even if it's too high.